# Android device monitor does not show database file in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-database

Android device monitor does not show database file in android studio.

Under `data/data/pakageName` it shows only two folder;

1. cache.
2. shared_pref

Note:data insertion and retrieval works perfectly.

plz help thanx in advance

Comment: make sure you are looking at the right place, I am using studio 1.5.1 and device monitor works just fine

Comment: for testing purposes you can also create database file in root folder of sd card

Comment: post an screenshot and where you are keeping the database.. make sure packageName is applicationId

Comment: Where you are installing app, in Device or emulator ?

Comment: the app is running on emulator @Sree

Comment: the database is stored under Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/mydabname"; @ Arnav M.

Comment: if you set path for the database, it will be created there, the `/data/data/` is the default in case you did not set a path alongside the db-name, please post the code you are using in your sqlitehelper class

Comment: @Yazan thanx  My problem solved .have a great day